# Is there any IDE for eos smart contract?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, eosjs, eosio-code, eosio.token

Is there any IDE for compiling eos smart contract? for example ethereum have remix to compile and run solidity based smart contract.

Comment: you can basically use every C/C++ compatible Editor/IDE you want. Common ones apart from EosStudio are VS Code, Atom, CLion, Eclipse etc

Comment: EOS Studio is one however keep in mind it's not open source.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is IDE for eosio you can try to this IDE https://www.eosstudio.io/

Answer (score 2):

https://www.eosstudio.io/

https://dev4eos.com/

I found two interesting tools, eosstudio is way better than dev4eos. The problem i found in eosstudio is, it's not open source and got lot of bugs while deploying and checking the contract state. The latter one is a complete mess, no active support, lots and lots of bugs

Comment: Bugs in eosio.cdt was the problem while compiling and deploying the smart contract using eos studio. Use older version of eosio cdt in eos studio to avoid compilation errors and bugs.

Comment: i have already tried that, eosstudio will show bugs on version 1.6.1(eosio.cdt),its will only compile smoothy over version 1.5.0(eosio.cdt). The bug I'm talking about is after deploying the contract,i cant interact with it.

Comment: Using an older Version of the cdt doesn't sound clever to me, better to switch the IDE then. @sachinmurali open a question and tell us about the bugs so we can try to help!

Comment: error while compiling code in eosstudio?.....search this